# Trying to break an array into three uneven arrays (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby, arrays

Here's the code that will yield an array (I believe it's an array) of 13 page titles. I'd like to have titles 0-5 be in its own div, 6-8 in a second div and 9-12 in a third, for dropdown menus. I couldn't find this exact question/answer here.

```
<% @cms_site.pages.root.children.published.each. do |page| %>
  <%= link_to page.label, page.full_path %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: But depend on what logic you want to break?

Comment: If you always want to break in that way you could just do 3 different loops over each portion of the array that you care about.

Comment: It would be helpful to both answerers and future visitors if you would describe a) why you want this, and b) what the logic is that is causing you to choose those ranges.

Comment: Why? Because a dropdown menu with 13 page choices is just too much for the reader! The 13 pages are logically grouped into three because they fall under the same general category. It's neater to have three buttons with descriptions, and I fancy the look.  Thanks.

Comment: So why are those choices grouped by index in the same array, instead of by some other ancillary criteria that you could use with a `group_by` call?

Comment: Ah, now I see why you asked the first questions.  The array is dynamically generated in comfy cms.  If I were a programmer, I might be able to code a decorator or something to do as you are suggesting. Thanks for sticking with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you attempted? `#each` is not a very good use for this case. You might want to separate it into 3 different loops like so:

```
<% @cms_site.pages.root.children.published[0,5].each do |page| %>
  <%= link_to page.label, page.full_path %>
<% end %>

<% @cms_site.pages.root.children.published[6,8].each do |page| %>
  <%= link_to page.label, page.full_path %>
<% end %>

<% @cms_site.pages.root.children.published[9,12].each do |page| %>
  <%= link_to page.label, page.full_path %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT** 
It seems like you're having some logic problems, it'd be wise for you to attempt it first at least.

The code up there should work but it's not really DRY and it can be extracted into maybe a helper method that uses the chapters for the iterator or possibly use a different iterator (e.g. `each_with_index`) and handle the check for each index in the block. There's many ways to go about doing what you asked.

Comment: This indeed works! I was putting the []after the .each instead of before! Stupid error. Thanks much. Now I'll try to make it more DRY in a helper.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you're dealing with an array and you want to take the exact same elements from it each time, here's how to slice it:

```
# Your Array
elements = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

# This will give you three arrays inside one array. The first will be first six
# elements starting from 0, the second is 3 elements starting from 6, etc.
arrays = [ elements[0,6], elements[6,3], elements[9,3] ]
```

Now you can iterate through the array and reuse the code to generate the code you want.

```
arrays.each do |ar|
  # Now render for each array as you please, and reuse the same code.
end
```